# Can't I use 'coalesce' as a solution for HDFS small file problem?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I'm really new to HDFS, and I trying to resolve small file problems while consuming logs from Kafka Connect Cluster.

Since there are many partitions on my Kakfa Topics and I consumed the log every 10 minutes, there are so many small files on my HDFS directory. (over 1500 files per day, and about 200kb per file)

So I wrote a simple pyspark code to merge those small files, as below.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

APP_NAME = "MERGE_SMALL_LOGS"

def analyze(ss: SparkSession, **args):
    route = args["route"]

    dataframe = ss.read.json(f"{route}/*.json")
    repartitioned_df = dataframe.coalesce(1).sort("timestamp")
    repartitioned_df.write.mode('append').json(route)
    repartitioned_df.write.mode('append').parquet(route)
```

However, when I run the script, it seems only the very part of the whole file has been saved as a new json&parquet file.

I thought `coalesce(1)` might not be a silver bullet in this case, but cannot find why the above thing happens.

Could `coalesce(1)` occurs OOM error while I fixed the partition size as '1'? Or are there other problems that I didn't consider on the above script? Or could be another way will be better to resolving small file problems in my case?

Thanks very much for reading, and any help will be very helpful.

Comment: Looks like you read JSON files **from `route`** then write it back at the **the same location**, so your job would read the same data over and over?

Comment: @pltc hi, I was planning to read the HDFS route by args, but I convert it as a static value because I think it is trivial in this question. I will change it anyway. thanks!

Comment: @pltc oh now I got what you said. thanks very much! I didn't noticed the mistake.